# How to list full path of files/directories using only ls command (working in a restricted shell)

Tags: command-line

I have restricted shell on Production environment servers in my company, leaving me with handful of command choices.

I am trying to get full path of files/directories using only **ls** command. I **can't** use xargs, sed, awk, find in the restricted shell, so I am only left with using options in the ls command.

I have tried below command but this doesn't recurse. I mention this as I came across this command while searching an answer for my problem.

`ls -lRt -d -1 $PWD/{*,.*}`

Here is the list of ALL the commands available to me in restricted shell. Let me be clear. I can't create any **function**, I can't use **read** command.

```
/usr/bin/cat
/usr/bin/clear
/usr/bin/cmp
/usr/bin/cut
/usr/bin/date
/usr/bin/df
/usr/bin/diff
/usr/bin/du
/usr/bin/grep
/usr/bin/head
/usr/bin/id
/usr/bin/ls
/usr/bin/od
/usr/bin/prstat
/usr/bin/ps
/usr/bin/sort
/usr/bin/tail
/usr/bin/wc
/usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/who
cd
echo
exit
pwd
```

Comment: What shell is it? ksh, bash, zsh, dash?

Comment: `echo $SHELL`
`/usr/SYSADM/bin/rbash`

Comment: Are _all_ built-in commands disabled (`set` , `compgen`, etc.)? What Unix is this?

Answer (score 1):

This command should do it as echo is available.

```
ls -Rr1 . |  while read line; do case $line in *:) basepath=${line%:};; "") basepath=;; *) echo "$basepath/$line";; esac; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell what subset of `bash` is implemented in `rbash`. If you are lucky, try

```
shopt -s globstar ## bash built in 
ls **/* *
```

(`*` lists files in the current directory, and `**/*` lists all files in all subdirectories, at whatever depth).

Comment: `**/*` does include the files in the current directory. In `bash -O globstar`, you can also do `ls -td -- **`

Answer (score 0):

The following function will list all files from a directory (`/` by default) in depth-first order without using even `ls`:

```
lsr(){
        for f in "$1/"* "$1/".[!.]* "$1/"..?*; do
                test -e "$f" && echo "$f"
                test -d "$f" && lsr "$f"
        done
}
```

Example:

```
$ lsr .
./dir
./dir/file
./dir/.dotfile
./.foo
./..bar
$ find . -depth
./dir/.dotfile
./dir/file
./dir
./.foo
./..bar
.
```

It can be made into a separate script instead of a function:

```
#! /bin/sh
for f in "$1/"* "$1/".[!.]* "$1/"..?*; do
        test -e "$f" && echo "$f"
        test -d "$f" && "$0" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks mosvy. But as I mentioned in my question, I have restricted shell with approximately 20 Unix commands allowed (e.g., cat, ls, df, du, tail, echo..) . So, I can't create a function or call another shell script. Unfortunately, I am only limited to using ls command and it's options. It is possible, that I may not have any way to fulfill my requirement with the extremely limited options that I have.

Comment: or `g=*; while ls -1d $g 2>/dev/null; do g="$g/*"; done`

Comment: or if you have `du`: `for f in \`du\`; do ls -ld "$f"/* "$f"/.* 2>/dev/null; done`

Comment: Please edit your question with the list of commands you have access to and mention the fact that you can't define functions (you should've done that from the beginning!)